# Terraform returns error "The resource type could not be found in the namespace" when creating azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-backup-vault

Terraform v1.0.4
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.73.0
Upgraded to v2.74.0 - issue persists.

When trying to create backup vault with terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault" "backupvault" {
  name                = "good-name-for-backup-vault"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.transport.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.transport.location
  datastore_type      = "VaultStore"
  redundancy          = "LocallyRedundant"
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

I get follow error:

```
Debug Output
Panic Output
│ Error: waiting for creation of the DataProtection BackupVault ("Backup Vault: (Name \"good-name-for-backup-vault\" /  
Resource Group \"transport-resources\")"): Future#WaitForCompletion: the number of retries has been exceeded:   
StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceType" Message="The resource type could not be found in the  
namespace 'Microsoft.DataProtection' for api version '2021-01-01'."
│
│   with azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault.backupvault,
│   on backup.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault" "backupvault":
│    1: resource "azurerm_data_protection_backup_vault" "backupvault" {
```

The thing is that Backup vault is created (if viewed from portal - you can see it), but terraform shows error and stops. And this worked worked 7 days ago just fine. But at least for last 3 days it started showing this error and stopping.

Also when deleting backup vault from portal I get similar error - "The resource type could not be found in namespace". But trying to delete it second time - it removes resource just fine then.
[Error when deleting resource through portal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT1d8.png)

**UPDATE:**

So error disappeared. Not sure what was the problem - but same code works now fine.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be an issue with the `DataProtection/BackupVaults` service.

**As per Microsoft Azure Team:**

`Between 15:00 UTC on 30 Aug. 2021 and 17:48 on 1 September 2021`, Users using BackupVaults might have experienced issues tracking DataProtection/BackupVaults management control plane operations. Impact may also have resulted in other operations that use validate APIs being blocked in the Azure Portal (like Vault creation, Backup Instance creation, Restore operations). Additionally, operations ran through Azure PowerShell and CLI were also effected.

**Preliminary root cause:** A Recent feature change caused a code regression in which the values that were incorrectly displayed within the BackupVaults manifest. As the backend ARM call would try to access the manifest, it was not able to find an end point corresponding to the service. This led to an issue tracking data protection management control plane operation with Azure portal Azure PowerShell, and CLI.

**Mitigation:** Azure technical team have applied a hotfix first to the BackupVaults Manifest which mitigated the issue.

**Note :** If you need a detailed RCA , then creating a support request might help you . You can create a Support request by going to (Help+support) in azure portal and creating a new technical support request.